# How to detect Menu Pop up android?

Tags: android, popup, android-viewtreeobserver

Is there any way to detect when the Menu Pop up is displayed?

After i click to Overflow Menu. The Menu which contains Settings, Tour, Walkthroughs doesn't get detected.

[image]

I tried the ViewTreeObserver Methods like

ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener, ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalFocusChangeListener, ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowAttachListener,
ViewTreeObserver.OnWindowFocusChangeListener

But non of the methods are called.

Is there any Listener to chich i can listen to.?

Comment: paste your code

Comment: Fixed the issue. Had forgotten to register the listener. This did the trick. getViewTreeObserver().addOnWindowFocusChangeListener(this);